# PlusOneButton replace deprecated API

Tags: android, google-plus

I got an old project with the following code :

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .useDefaultAccount()
            .build();
```

`Plus.API` and `Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN` is **deprecated**
Now on the device **G+ button** works correctly. How to change the code to remove the warning ?